# Laravel OOP: trying to call a var in a function that has been declared in the same class

Tags: laravel, controller

i'm in my pages controller trying to call a variable in a function that has been declared in the same class, it's not working properly.

**When I put the vars back in the function, all works good.**

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
public $Fname = 'Mobile';
public $Lname ='Store';
    public function about()
    {

        return view('pages.about', compact('Fname', 'Lname'));
                }

    public function contact()
    {
         $Fname = 'Mobile';
         $Lname ='Store';

        return view('pages.contact', compact('Fname', 'Lname'));


    }

}
```

I'm receiving an **Undefined variable: Fname** error.
Thanks.
Erez

Answer (score 0):

first you have to look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).
this is simple oops concept not a laravel error at all.

```
public function about()
{
    $Fname = $this->Fname;
    $Lname = $this->Lname;

    return view('pages.about', compact('Fname', 'Lname'));
}
```

Comment: ofcourse it's not a Laravel error, I've never said it was.
In anycase, from what your writing, the best way is to declare vars into each function separately. If that's the only case, so be it... 
But if there is a more elegant way from the class or by referencing, that would simply be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
public function about()
    {
        $Fname=$this->Fname;
        $Lname=$this->Lname;
        return view('pages.about', compact('Fname', 'Lname'));

}
```

Comment: No. Same Answer. After submitting mine, i noticed yours :)

Comment: thanks for both of your answers, but isn't there a shorter more "Laravel way" of writing this?

Comment: No, you can also use     return $view->with('Fname', $this->Fname)->with('Lname', $this->Lname);

Comment: with() is using flash session so that's not a preferred way.